# Disable QGis Tips Panel when application start

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to disable the QGIS Tips Panel with config files. I use QGIS Lyon.
- QGIS2.ini
- And a custom file define with the parameter --customizationfile

[image]

I know the user can click on "I've had enough tips, don't show this on start up any more!" and he never see this window again. But I would like this Panel never show (even the first time).

I start QGIS with this command

```
qgis.bat --configpath 'C:\gis' --optionspath 'C:\gis' --customizationfile 'C:\gis\QGISCONFIG.ini' --lang en_US
```

Maybe with a plugin ?

Comment: This can be configured in the config file (~/.config/QGIS/QGSI2.conf on Ubuntu). I have an entry `showTips=false` at the beginning of the `[Qgis]` section (line 171 in my case). You should find a way to edit this file before launching qgis.

Comment: Why not writing your comment as an answer, @ArMoraer?

Comment: Well, I think this is just a lead and not a full answer (unless user2382684 doesn't need more info?). But I'm still new to GIS SE rules^^

Comment: @ArMoraer your comment is the full answer.  There is no other way from the command line to disable tips.  Make it the answer so you get the points for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be configured in the config file (`~/.config/QGIS/QGSI2.conf` on Ubuntu). I have an entry showTips=false at the beginning of the [Qgis] section (line 171 in my case). You should find a way to edit this file before launching qgis.

Comment: Thanks ArMoraer. This is the solution. I am on Windows so I use a QGIS2.ini and from my version of QGIS you need to call the parameter showTips212 (212 for the release number).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep any other aspects of the configuration you can script this like:

> mkdir -p /root/.config/QGIS/
>   sh -c 'printf "[Qgis]\nshowTips208=false">/root/.config/QGIS/QGIS2.conf'

I used it with Kartoza's Docker image and `xvfb-run qgis` to run it headless, but remember to update the `showTips208` to your version. `208` is the one for QGIS 2.8.