# Disable QGIS Tips in Python on startup file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to create a portable QGIS. It can be done by copy the folder of QGIS2 and put in other computer. And if I want to run python in startup, I have to put the startup file in `C:\Users\USER\.qgis2\python`.

So, I can't do it the way in : [Disable QGis Tips Panel when application start](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177034/disable-qgis-tips-panel-when-application-start)

I want to do this in python. I have to input the script in startup file. So, how could I script this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the QGIS tips, you could use the following in your startup script (assuming this is for QGIS 2.18):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/showTips218", False)
```

Comment: @mega - Most welcome, glad it works :)